Approximating binomial with normal distribution
You wanted to estimate how many packages were damaged in a shipment of $5000$ packages. You randomly selected $300$ packages and found that 16 of them were damaged. Determine the lower bound of the two-sided confidence interval for the total number of damaged packages in the shipment. The confidence interval should have an approximate confidence level of $95\%$
My question:
I assumed a binomial distribution $Bin(5000, \frac{16}{300})$ because they are asking the total number. But in the solution they did $Bin(300, \frac{16}{300})$. I did everything else almost correctly but I still cannot see why n=300.
Another thing I also found a little confusing is that they are using z-distribution but since we are approximating everyhting, shouldn't they have used t-distribution. I'd really appreciate it someone could clear that up for me.

The only observation we have is the $300$ element sample.  If $p$ is the desired probability, we need to get a confidence interval for $p$ given that we observed $16$ fails out of $300$.

@lulu but they are asking for total number tho? Also what about the z-distribution?

They are asking for $p$, the total size is irrelevant.  And you are interested in the range $[p_{min}, p_{max}]$ which has the property that, for $p$ taken outside this range, the probability that you'd see exactly $16$ fails is $<.05$ (Note that taking $p=\frac {16}{300}$  gives a value over $.1$).  This is a $z-$score question.  For instance, taking $p=.1$ yields a probability of $.001$ so $.1>p_{max}$, just as an illustration.

As another way to look at it:  Consider the standard error involved in using the sample mean as a surrogate for the true (but unknown) mean.
